# How to draw pie chart on my project

Tags: php, mysql, css, charts, pie-chart

I have mysql database and I want to create pie chart and the pie chart it should be take the an action based on my database?

I have look around some solution suggest to use google library but i try this but don't want this because i will implement my project offline without internet access

suppose this query

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(af_student_id) AS total2 FROM assessment_form WHERE job =' yes '";


$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(af_student_MAJOR) AS total2 FROM assessment_form WHERE job =' yes '";
```

Comment: You'll need to send that data to the browser in some format (probably json or xml) and render it with a javascript charting library.

Comment: While js chart libraries are probably the best solution in terms of flexibility, you can also create pie charts with HTML/CSS only: http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2011/how-to-create-pie-charts-with-css3/ However, this is not the way to go with lots of dynamic data imho.

Answer (score 1):

You can check Highcharts library or Chart.js library.

Output the data to browser in json format, and render it as a pie chart by using these javascript library.

Include these library in your project so it can be used offline.